# Need to hit this nail on the head... retaining fragment and view onConfigurationChange

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, onconfigurationchanged

We have a web service which serves up an XML file via a HTTP Post.

I am downloading and parsing this xml file into an object to populate some views inside a couple of fragments held in a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I get this XML file via an `AsyncTask` and it tells my fragments the process has finished via a listener interface.

From there, I populate the view inside the fragment with data returned from the web service. This is all fine until the orientation changes. From what I understand, the `ViewPager`'s adapter is supposed to retain the fragments it's created, which is fine, and which I want to happen, and I know the fragment's `onCreateView` method is still called to return the view. I've spent the last day or so hunting through posts here and the Google docs etc and I can't find a concrete method that lets me do what I want to do: retain the fragment, and it's already populated view so that I can simply restore it when the orientation changes and avoid unneccesary calls to the web service.

Some code snippets:

In the main activities `onCreate`:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
if (mViewPager != null) {
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    if (CheckCredentials()) {
        Refresh(0,0);
    } else {
        ShowCredentialsDialog(false);
    }
}
```

Refresh method in main activity...

```
public void Refresh(Integer month, Integer year) {
    if (mUpdater == null) {
        mUpdater = new UsageUpdater(this);
//        mUpdater.setDataListener(this);
    }

    if (isConnected()) {
        mUpdater.Refresh(month, year);
        usingCache = false;
        mProgress.show();
    } else {
        mUpdater.RefreshFromCache();
        usingCache = true;
    }
}
```

This is the entire Fragment in question, minus some of the UI populating code as it's not important to show the setting of text in textviews etc...

```
public class SummaryFragment extends Fragment implements Listeners.GetDataListener {

    private static final String KEY_UPDATER = "usageupdater";
    private UsageUpdater mUpdater;
    private Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.ctx = activity;
    }

    private View findViewById(int id) {
        return ((Activity)ctx).findViewById(id);
    }

    public void onGetData() {
        // AsyncTask interface method, will be called from onPostExecute.
        // Populate view from here
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usagesummary, container, false);
        mUpdater = (UsageUpdater) getArguments().getSerializable(KEY_UPDATER);
        mUpdater.setDataListener(this);
        return view;
    }
}
```

If I understand any of this 'issue' it's that I'm returning an empty view in `onCreateView` but I don't know how to retain the fragment, return it's view prepopulated with data and manage all web service calling from the main activity.

In case you can't tell, Android is not a primary language for me and this probably looks a shambles. Any help is appreciated I'm getting rather frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any alternative resources when the Activity is re-created, you could try handling the rotation event yourself by using configChange flags in your AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    ... />
```

There is no way to keep the same, pre-populated Views if your Activity is re-created since this would cause a Context leak:

http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: I've read that this is against best practice so I am avoiding doing it. I also don't want to retain a portrait view when the phone is in a landscape orientation. I know what I want to do can be done because plenty of applications do it, but I'm trying to find the correct method for achieving it.

Comment: Then what you'll likely want to do is put a `Fragment` in your MainActivity layout that contains your `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` as well as the data backing the Adapter.

in the top level Fragment's `onSaveInstanceState()`, save the data backing your current view:
    ...
    outState.putString(key, string); // etc, etc for all the data backing your view
    ...

then in onCreateView() of the top level Fragment:

    ...
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        // restore state by recreating your adapter, by changing the selected page, putting data into the fragment, etc
    }

Comment: That was in reply to @sddamico's comment, not the original answer.